# rtf difference format on mac os x and windows

Tags: windows, macos, rtf

I try to use objective-c codes to read the rtf(has images) on mac osx.
I noticed that app Textedit on mac always removes the image info of the rtf file.
I check the binary codes of rtf on Windows. rtf file always change the images in to long text strings .

I am not sure if the rtf definition on mac and win have the difference?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I remind that Mac OS X Textedit uses RTFD format when you add images and Windows keep on RTF and puts directly the datas IN the textfile.

RTFD is a package format (it's a folder in fact) and store the images as files and text separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of correct.

Windows uses and implements the full RTF spec, which allows for embedded images to be written as either Hex code or Hex code converted to binary code.

On Mac, TextEdit will read RTF files just fine but it does not implement the entire spec. Specifically TextEdit ignores RTF streams which have embedded images. This is pure laziness on Apple's part. Instead Apple likes to use RTFD containers which have the image and the RTF code links to that image. Unfortunately these containers do not work in Windows.

What this means? There is no real RTF compatibility between TextEdit and Windows and vice versa. This is a very frustrating problem that has been around for a very long time.

I have filed bug reports with Apple to request that they support the RTF spec. Version 1.9 can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725).